# OpenSSL decryption in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, openssl, encryption

I have a PHP webpage, where I use OpenSSL to encrypt a text in PHP (openssl_private_decrypt).

Encripted text:

> bhYtdNghwutjxqgHg8AoyebLm5AY+X/4GLNzzb0PVuyiUX2QKwwDBXH4kVQFJIqUUrm6nYGk740wWkSoAMzygA==
>   Public key: -----BEGIN PUBLIC
>   KEY-----MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAMYQWDqtLgDKlQvWzacGeBMQpbicd/uoXAvgLNpFZLM7zuYFDhrYncRsl8LIHK0K3f7e1aFmUVgM4LrKU2WFIw0CAwEAAQ==-----END
>   PUBLIC KEY-----

I don't know how to decrypt it in a browser in JavaScript. I'm looking for some code or library, which I can decode it.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually instead of letting the browser and web server handle it automatically by using HTTPS?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3977325/861940

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer:

I found an encryption algorithm in this page:
https://github.com/ziyan/javascript-rsa (You need the rsa.js and jsbn.js)

But it only contains the encryption algorithm, and some characters are encrypted bad.

I have written a decryption code into the js, and changed the code that makes an error in the encryption.

And you'll need the following libraries from [here](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/)!

- prng4.js
- rng.js

Finally you should change the following text for [this](http://pastebin.com/GfhuDwj5):

```
var RSA = {
   ...
}
```

I hope it can help somebody.
Horbert

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try out forge as well -- it does RSA encryption/decryption and more. There are lots of examples on the README:

https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Answer (score 0):

What you could also use is our NoSSL, it is open-source and free for private/non-commercial use: 
http://www.nossl.net
There is also an Indiegogo campaign right now: 
http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/nossl-security-for-your-website/x/6399437